# iOS Orientation Change with ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, uiwebview, orientation, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have an app that is a single view: a UIWebView that gets pdfs loaded into it. The pdfs are loaded from an ECSlidingViewController.

For some reason, when the app goes from portrait to landscape, the WebView remains in the same position and there is a large dark area to the left of the screen.

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

I have tried a number of techniques, but they each have problems. For example I can't simply reload a landscape view when the orientation changes, the user will lose their place in the webview. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're Auto resize mask is wrong. How is your view heirrarchy built?

Comment: This is my first iPad app, I'm not entirely sure. How would I know?

Comment: I had this working a while ago, and then we had to return to the project. Now there is a new iOS version and the settings are a lot different. It seems like this should be the simplest thing to do: When it's portrait, be like X, when in landscape be like Y.

Comment: this happens in iOS 9 for previously working projects.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?